# Overriding the `[]` operator in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to implement a class which provides a dictionary with a default value:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Dict:
    def __init__(self, default) -> None:
        self.default = default
        self.values = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values[key] if key in self.values else deepcopy(self.default)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.values[key] = value
```

It works as expected when the default value is "plain" (`42` in the example below):

```
KEY = 'k'
d = Dict(42)
print(d[KEY]) # prints 42
d[KEY] = 53
print(d[KEY]) # prints 53
```

But it doesn't work as expected when the default value is by itself a `Dict` object:

```
KEY1 = 'k1'
KEY2 = 'k2'
d = Dict(Dict(42))
print(d[KEY1][KEY2]) # prints 42
d[KEY1][KEY2] = 53
print(d[KEY1][KEY2]) # prints 42
```

I have tried to debug that by adding various printouts within the class functions, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this just an exercise because you're curious, or should you just be using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: @larsks: Not an exercise, I need this for work. I wasn't aware of `defaultdict` so I will have a look at it now. Tx!

Comment: @larsks: I have, and I'm not sure how to use it instead of the class that I've implemented here; Would you be able to help on that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is in your `__getitem__` method:

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values[key] if key in self.values else deepcopy(self.default)
```

Because you're only *returning* a value here, but not actually setting it, the returned value isn't useful. If you request a key that doesn't exist, the method is equivalent to:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return deepcopy(self.default)
```

So when you write:

```
d[KEY1][KEY2] = 53
```

You're successfully setting a value for `KEY2`, but only in the dictionary returned by `__getitem__`. You probably want to use the dictionary `setdefault` method, which will set the key in `self.values` if it doesn't exist (in addition to returning it):

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values.setdefault(key, deepcopy(self.default))
```

With this implementation:

```
>>> KEY1 = 'k1'
>>> KEY2 = 'k2'
>>> d = Dict(Dict(42))
>>> print(d[KEY1][KEY2])
42
>>> d[KEY1][KEY2] = 53
>>> print(d[KEY1][KEY2])
53
```

---

But as I mentioned in my comment, a better solution is just to use the existing [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) implementation:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 42))
>>> d[KEY1][KEY2]
42
>>> d[KEY1][KEY2]=53
>>> d[KEY1][KEY2]
53
```

(The difference between `defaultdict` and the class you implemented is that the default must be a callable. Here's I've used `lambda` expressions, but you could also use actual functions, classes, etc).

Comment: Wow this is truly  awesome, thank you so much!!! I think that what I was really missing here (on top of knowing about the `defaultdict` utility, because I've managed to "reimplement" that in my class), is the `lambda` trick, which is kind of a function pointer really. I knew how to do that in JS, but not in Python. Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm glad you included defaultdict, otherwise that setdefault with an expensive default evaluation every time would really irk me :-). I already feel a little bad every time I use it with just `[]` as default.

Comment: Btw, another option (but also not as good as defaultdict): A dict subclass implementing [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__).

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using deepcopy so it creates a copy without reference.
You have to return the object without deepcopy.

`def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values[key] if key in self.values else self.default`

Now it should work as expected.

Comment: Dropping `deepcopy` means that if your default is a complex type, like a `dict` or a `list`, this will have unexpected and probably undesirable behavior. Try `d = Dict(Dict({'foo': 'bar'}))`, and then set `d['a']['b']['foo'] = 3`. Now look at `d['a']['c']['foo']`. Oops!